# ECONNRESET Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am suddenly getting this error & there is no way I am able to trace the issue, my server keeps crashing again & again, and I haven’t done any changes in months for sure.

```
events.js:288
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
    Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    errno: 'ECONNRESET',
    code: 'ECONNRESET',
    syscall: 'read'
}
```

Anyone facing this issue or have solution to the crash?

I tried to comment as much code as possible to avoid this issue but no luck.

Can anyone help me if this error was faced by anyone?

Comment: This looks very on the node-level, do you have performance metrics on recent I/O, CPU and RAM usage? Storage volume full?

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be due to your connection,
may be you lost your internet connection or from your server so check your server is that running properly or not

Comment: Its not a connection problem, that I am sure of